# Ricci tensor for an orthonormal basis from Eigenchris' Tensor Calculus video 24

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I am working through a YouTuber's (called Eigenchris) video series on Tensor Calculus. I have really enjoyed the visual and intuitive approach he takes. However, I have a question that has stumped me from video 24 on the Ricci Tensor. Any help would be appreciated.

At the 24:40 mark for in Tensor Calculus 24 by Eigenchris, he derives the Ricci tensor from the sum of sectional curvatures in an orthonormal basis.
$$Ric(\vec{v}, \vec{v}) = \sum_{i=1}^{D} K(\vec{e}_i,\vec{v}) = \frac{\left[R(\vec{e}_i,\vec{v} )\vec{v}\right]\cdot\vec{e}_i}{(\vec{e}_i\cdot\vec{e}_i)(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}) - (\vec{e}_i\cdot\vec{v})^2}$$
Since the basis is orthonormal, the denominator goes to 1.
$$Ric(\vec{v}, \vec{v}) =[R(\vec{e}_i,\vec{v} )\vec{v}]\cdot\vec{e}_i $$
The next line of reasoning stumps me because he says that we can expand $\vec{v}$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors. Other commenters pointed out that this cannot be done if $\vec{v}$ is part of the orthonormal basis.
The derivation goes on as follows:
$$Ric(\vec{v}, \vec{v}) = [R(\vec{e}_i,v^j\vec{e}_j )v^k\vec{e}_k]\cdot\vec{e}_i $$
$$Ric(\vec{v}, \vec{v}) = v^jv^k[R(\vec{e}_i,\vec{e}_j )\vec{e}_k]\cdot\vec{e}_i$$
$$Ric(\vec{v}, \vec{v}) =v^jv^kR^i_{kij} = v^jv^kR_{kj}$$
My question is:

How can we properly expand $\vec{v}$ in order to get the components of the Ricci Tensor for an orthonormal basis as Eigenchris does?

Answer (score 1):

> Other commenters pointed out that this cannot be done if $v$ is part of the orthonormal basis.

I don't know why people are saying that.
A basis by definition spans the entire vector space - every vector can be decomposed as you have it
$$v= \sum_i v^ie_i.$$
(This is kind of the whole point of a basis.)

If $v$ happens to be equal to one of the basis vectors, $v=e_j$, then this just means all the $v^i$'s are zero except for $v^j=1$.

Comment: In that case would the last line just change to $v^k v^k = R_{kk}$?

Comment: Your comment is messed up. You mean $R_{jj}$?

Comment: yeah in the case that v is one of the basis vectors e_m, then we have $v^i = \delta^i_m$ (the kronecker delta). Then your last line is
$$
\sum_{j,k} v^jv^k R_{jk} = \sum_{j,k}\delta^j_m \delta^k_m R_{jk} = R_{mm}
$$